# Issue with JavaScript in Rails application C9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to code a personality quiz using JS in a rails application on C9 but I can't seem to get the javascript working. I've written a couple of test quizzes and none of them have worked. Below is a copy of an example which works on JSfiddle but wont work in my application:

The javascript is in a file named rec located in the javascripts folder in assets:

```
var form = document.forms.survey

function getValues () {
    // add your <input> names to this array:
    return [
        'bee',
        'camel',
        'eagle'
    ].reduce(function (obj, cur) {
        var input = form[cur]
        obj[cur] = input.checked ? Number(input.value) : 0
        return obj
    }, {})
}

function computeResults (values) {
    // adjust your equation here:
    return values.bee + values.camel*2 - values.eagle
}

// show the result in the DOM
function showResults (total) {
    document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = total
}

// when the form is submitted, compute and show the result
document.getElementsByName('survey')[0].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault() // prevent the browser from redirecting the page
    showResults(computeResults(getValues()))
})
```

and the html within a view:

```
<form name="survey">

    What is your favorite animal?

    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bee" value="1" />
        Bee
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="camel" value="1" />
        Camel
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="eagle" value="1" />
        Eagle
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Go!" id="submit" />

    Total is: <span id="total"></span>

</form>
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? An error? Some function not being run? Have you looked at the Javascript console for errors?

Comment: The JavaScript doesnt seem to be called in the view, in the example above when I click submit the value called doesnt show, but the page refreshes.

Comment: Try wrapping all your Javascript in a `document.ready` function. (might be easier to disable Turbolinks while debugging this) Also check that you're selecting the correct elements before calling `addEventListener`

Comment: I'm new to JavaScript, im not quite sure what you mean, could you elaborate, or give me an example please?

Comment: Added document ready and it works! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to wrap your Javascript in a document ready function.

Keep in mind that rails by default includes turbo links, which causes some unexpected behavior relating to document ready. Search around stack overflow to see how to use the two together. I'm sure there's a number of tutorials out there.